# Bad Bottom Spacing For Equation After Section

Tags: math-mode, spacing, sectioning

As shown below the bottom spacing after the first equation is smaller than it should be to look right. I know I could manually add space, but is there a way to fix this automatically? I do know I should not place equations right after sections but I do feel that it works best in my case.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\setlength\mathindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section*{Test}
\[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
This is some test text.
\[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
This is some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this after `\section`: `\mbox{}\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topskip}`.  See ADDENDUM for possible general fix:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\setlength\mathindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section*{Test}
\mbox{}\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topskip}
\[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
This is some test text.
\[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
This is some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

To confirm that the before spacing is correct, one can place text in the `\mbox` and compare:

[image]

I confirmed that it works, regardless of the `\parskip` value.

**ADDENDUM**

Not sure if this will break other things, but here, I redefine `\[` to apply the prior fix but only if in vertical mode.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}

\let\sveqopen\[
\def\[{\ifvmode\mbox{}\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topskip}\fi\sveqopen}

\begin{document}
\section*{Test}
\[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
This is some test text.
\[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
This is some more text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this automatically? Such as an environment that would automatically fix this issue?

Comment: @cabellicar123 At the moment, I can't think of an auto-fix, but I would in the preamble define `\def\fixmath{\mbox{}\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topskip}}` and then just use `\fixmath` in the text, if an equation was needed immediately after a `\section`.

Comment: @cabellicar123  See possible general fix in addendum.

Comment: @cabellicar123 egreg is much more savvy than I, so perhaps the ideal solution would combine both our solutions:  `\let\sveqopen\[
\def\[{\ifvmode\mbox{}\vspace{\glueexpr-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\abovedisplayskip}\fi\sveqopen}`.

Answer (score 3):

The first equation uses the “short” skips, because the paragraph before it is empty. You have to make it artificially longer and to back up by a baseline skip plus the above display skip.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\setlength\mathindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section*{Test}
\makebox[.8\linewidth]{}\vspace{\glueexpr-\baselineskip-\abovedisplayskip}
\[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
This is some test text.
\[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
This is some more text.

\end{document}
```

You will get the normal spacing between the section title and the equation.

[image]

Here's a visual proof that the spacing is correct:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to make the spacing between the section and the equation slightly smaller. Is there a way to keep that while still fixing the spacing on bottom?

Comment: @cabellicar123 Don't trust your eyes. `;-)` I added a visual proof that the distance between base lines is the same.

Comment: Ah you are correct. Perhaps it is a time for my eyes to take a break. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to remove the extra space at the bottom say if I have a section right after the equation as well?

Comment: @cabellicar123 You get the usual space separating the text and the section title.